# How to fix the 504 error in API Gateway on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, api-gateway

I'm using API Gateway to create a REST API where I can run my API which is **hosted via docker and jenkins**, setup on aws ec2.

But whenever I try to send the request through API Gateway, I get the error of 504

[The error message on API Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1WqF.png)

However, when I hit the API through postman, I'm able to get a successful GET Request.

[Successful message on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re9nt.png)

This is how I know I'm hitting the correct API successfully but I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting a 504 error message on API Gateway.

Comment: Please consider posting meaningful information as text rather than image.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure that your backend integration includes only the logic needed for API Gateway to send an HTTP response to the client. Consider moving any nondependent or post-processing logic to another service, such as AWS Lambda.
> If network latencies are causing the 504 error, implement retry logic on the client-side application.